# In what cases would set.add() fail?

Tags: java, collections, set

Here's the code confusing me:

```
public class BoundedHashSet<T> {
    private final Set<T> set;
    private final Semaphore sem;
    public BoundedHashSet(int bound) {
        this.set = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<T>());
        sem = new Semaphore(bound);
    }
    public boolean add(T o) throws InterruptedException {
        sem.acquire();
        boolean wasAdded = false;
        try {
            wasAdded = set.add(o);    <-- line 1
            return wasAdded;
        }
        finally {
            if (!wasAdded)    <-- line 2
                sem.release();
        }
    }
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        boolean wasRemoved = set.remove(o);
        if (wasRemoved)
            sem.release();
        return wasRemoved;
    }
}
```

I found that `line 2` assumes that the `line 1` might fail, but I don't know in what cases the failure would happen.

I've looked through the Javadoc, Here's the exceptions `set.add(o)` might throw:

> Throws:
>
> **UnsupportedOperationException** - if the add operation is not supported by this set
>
> **ClassCastException** - if the class of the specified element prevents it from being added to this set
>
> **NullPointerException** - if the specified element is null and this set does not permit null elements
>
> **IllegalArgumentException** - if some property of the specified element prevents it from being added to this set

My question is, in this snippet, what exceptions would the code throw, which make the `set.add(o` fail?

Comment: It will fail for all the reasons you listed.  Also, a set is a distinct collection of objects.  If the object you're adding already exists, it will return false.

Comment: Since you seem to be very new: look at the meaning of the returned value. Exceptions are something different and not important in this snippet.

Answer (score 2):

There is no *"failure"* involved here,

From the [javadoc of `Set#add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-):

> Returns:
>   true if this set did not already contain the specified element